# Is it possible to tell whether an NDB cursor has been reversed?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

From GAE docs a reversed cursor can be made by:

`rev_cursor = cursor.reversed()`

I am looking for something like `cursor.is_reversed()` that will return whether the cursor has been reversed or not.

Does that exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, no such information is retained. The `.reversed()` call simply returns a new cursor with reversed positions:

```
def reversed(self):
    """Creates a cursor for use in a query with a reversed sort order."""
    for pos in self.__compiled_cursor.position_list():
        if pos.has_start_key():
            raise datastore_errors.BadRequestError('Cursor cannot be reversed.')

    rev_pb = datastore_pb.CompiledCursor()
    rev_pb.CopyFrom(self.__compiled_cursor)
    for pos in rev_pb.position_list():
        pos.set_start_inclusive(not pos.start_inclusive())
    return Cursor(_cursor_pb=rev_pb)
```

(Source re-indented to a 4-space indent for readability).